# JQuery - How to loop through JSON using each

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have cached the JSON returned from an Ajax call and need to loop through this to display it.  I get the error, 'Cannot read property 'title' of undefined'.  Can anyone help?

```
 $.each(cache['cat-'+cat], function(i, jd) {               
    var title= jd.title;  //issue is here
  )}
```

When I `console.log(cache['cat-'+cat])` I get the below:

```
Object {
  date: "2016-07-28T15:08:03.596Z", 
  data: '[{"id":471,"title":"Lines and Calls","solution_areas":"lines-calls"}]'
}
```

When I console.log(jd) within the loop I get the below:

```
2016-07-28T15:13:14.553Z
```

if I use `console.log(jd.data);`    I get

> undefined

I have tried the below but they don't work either:

```
var title= jd.data.title;  
var title= jd.data[0].title;
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: So there're quotes around the value of `data`?

Comment: in your example there is, so then it would need to be parsed again, since it's just a string...

Comment: I dont see the quotes

Comment: After `data:` and before `}`

Comment: Ahh yes you are right.   I have used stringify twice.  var cache = { date: new Date(), data: JSON.stringify(jd) };
      localStorage.setItem('cat-presentation-solution_areas-'+solutionarea, JSON.stringify(cache));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Just need to understand what is JSON and what is STRING

**cache['cat-'+cat].data** return a string that need to convert to JSON before pass to each loop:

```
var dataCacheReturned = cache['cat-'+cat];

var objCache = dataCacheReturned.data; //Its return a string 
objCache = JSON.parse(objCache); //Parse string to json

$.each(objCache, function(i, jd) {
  var title = jd.title; 
  console.log(title);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you are currently using it, `each` is going to iterate over every property of the `cache['cat-'+cat]` object, of which there are two, `date` and `data`.

So your anonymous function `function(i, jd)`will be called twice. The first time, `jd`will be the value of the `date` property (a string), the second time it will be the value of the `data` property (also a string, that happens to be formatted as JSON).

The contents of `data` need to be parsed before they can be accessed as an object/array, and given that `data` is formatted as an array, I am guessing that you actually want to iterate over that. Given the example provided, I would change it to:

```
$.each(JSON.parse(cache['cat-'+cat].data), function(i, jd) {               
    var title= jd.title;  
 });
```

Comment: What's the point of iterating? There's just one item inside `data`.

Comment: @nicael - If the data array only ever contains one object, there is none. But given that it IS an array (once parsed), it's likely that LeeTee intends for it to be populated with multiple objects at some point. Thus requiring iteration.

Comment: @ultrajohn - Where?

Comment: lol, sorry, of course, that JSON string gets parsed into a collection...

Comment: Sorry, Yes it will have an array, the above example did not, my bad

Comment: @LeeTee This answer does exactly provide the solution for array with multiple elements inside.

Comment: jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in

Comment: Yes, it was the string issue giving that error so @Govind was correct

Answer (score 1):

You aren't accessing it properly. And since `cache['cat-'+cat]` is already the needed object, what's the purpose of `$.each`? Should be

```
var title= JSON.parse(cache['cat-'+cat].data)[0].title;
```

(because the title is in the `data`, and the `data` is JSON).

Demo:

```js
var obj = {
  date: "2016-07-28T15:08:03.596Z", 
  data: '[{"id":471,"title":"Lines and Calls","solution_areas":"lines-calls"}]'
};
var title= JSON.parse(obj.data)[0].title; 
console.log(title);
```

Comment: Have I missed something? Please comment :)

Comment: @Rory I'm parsing the `data` attribute, it's JSON, not object.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. Don't know what it's for then. The downvote fairies seem out in force at the moment

Comment: DATA  will be an array in some cases,  the above example had only one object.  Sorry should have provided a better example